# How to access a Listener's source

Tags: java, swing, listener

I'm trying to use a generic ActionListener that makes something to the comboBox that called it using Java and Swing.

Is there a way to access the source of the ActionEvent and get it as a comboBox in order to access its methods such as getSelectedIndex() or setSelectedIndex()?
Would that be applicable to a FocusListener as well?

Thank you.

EDIT:

Example:

```
private class CbModalidadFocusListener extends FocusAdapter {
    @Override
    public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
        selection = someComboBox.getSelectedIndex();
    }
}
```

The desired behaviour would be something like:

selection = e.getSource().getSelectedIndex();

EDIT2:

ANSWER:

As Yole said, a cast is needed so:

( (JComboBox) e.getSource() ).getSelectedIndex()

Comment: your question is kind of vague. Could you please give a minimal example of what is not working and explain with the example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All AWT events have a getSource() method that returns what you need: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EventObject.html#getSource%28%29

Comment: Yes, but it seems I need to refine that in order to use methods over getSource()'s return.

Comment: Yes, you need to cast the result of getSource() to a specific control type. The AWT API was designed before Java had generics, so there is no solution that lets you avoid the cast.